# TEST Instruction and AND Instruction x86

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I'm converting C code into x86 Assembly and I have the line:

```
if (bitmask & bit)
```

I used gcc to produce the assembly code and this part was:

```
andl %edx, %eax
testl %eax, %eax
je else
```

(EAX is bit and EDX is bitmask)

Is the `andl` instruction necessary or would it work with a modified `testl` like this:

```
testl %edx, %eax
je else
```

?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The question cannot be answered by the information given. What optimization level are you useing?

Comment: @Olaf: This does not have to do with optimization.  the OP wants to know whether `testl` is necessary, and his confusion seems to be whether `andl` sets ZF or not, or perhaps he does not know that `je` needs ZF to be appropriately set.

Comment: @EricJ. My guess is that the real question the original poster is asking is "Why is GCC generating this apparently unnecessary instruction?".

Comment: @EricJ. if it's not necessary, then we should drop the [gcc] tag, and the C code and restrict it strictly to assembly, no?

Comment: @EvanCarroll: It's not my question, but I do feel that context is relevant to the question and wouldn't personally remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need the `testl` or `andl`, but not both.

Let's look at the code generated by GCC

The code

```
andl %edx, %eax
```

places the result of the and operation into %eax.

> Performs a bitwise AND operation on the destination (first) and source (second) operands and stores the result in
>   the destination operand location. The source operand can be an immediate, a register, or a memory location; the
>   destination operand can be a register or a memory location. (However, two memory operands cannot be used in
>   one instruction.) Each bit of the result is set to 1 if both corresponding bits of the first and second operands are 1;
>   otherwise, it is set to 0.
>
> The OF and CF flags are cleared; the SF, ZF, and PF flags are set according to the result. The state of the AF flag is
>   undefined.

http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf

(Page 121 and 122 of the PDF)

Now let's look at `testl`

```
testl %eax, %eax
```

`testl` also performs the same *and* that you just performed in the specific line.

Specifically testl

> Computes the bit-wise logical AND of first operand (source 1 operand) and the second operand (source 2 operand) and sets the SF, ZF, and PF status flags according to the result. The result is then discarded.
>
> In 64-bit mode, using a REX prefix in the form of REX.R permits access to additional registers (R8-R15). Using a REX prefix in the form of REX.W promotes operation to 64 bits. See the summary chart at the beginning of this section for encoding data and limits.

http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/TEST.html

In this case both operands are the same, the result of `andl`.  If the operand is 0, anding it with itself produces 0.  Anding any other value with itself produces a non-zero value.

**In Summary**

I'm unsure why GCC is producing both the `andl` and `testl` instruction.  I don't see a scenario where both would be necessary, as `testl` performs the *and* operation and both set the ZF needed by the `je` instruction.

Comment: The `andl` instruction sets the Z flag according to the result.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Can you cite a source?  I haven't done assembly for... 20 years?  But the sources I just looked up do not state that ZF is set for `andl`.

Comment: Could it be reduced to just `testl %edx, %eax` if saving EAX & EDX isn't important?

Comment: The [official intel instruction set reference](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) says: `The OF and CF flags are cleared; the SF, ZF, and PF flags are set according to the result. The state of the AF flag is undefined.` In other words, `test` is exactly equivalent to `and`, with the result discarded.

Comment: @Jester: Any thoughts on why GCC would produce the `andl`, if it is not needed under any circumstances?  If there are never possible side effects, surely it would not have been emitted even without any optimizations enabled.

Comment: @EricJ.: I presume the code has been translated without optimization, thus the `AND` if for the extression and the `TESTL` is to test the `if` condition. An optimization step might fold them to a single operation. But you do not answer the question. `TESTL` alone would be sufficient, as OP assumed.

Comment: @Olaf: I modified my answer to make it clearly correct (I believe) by adding the word "just" and adding a summary.  I would have deleted it, but cannot as it is accepted.  Since it cannot be deleted, let me know if you think anything else needs to change to make it correct.

Comment: I'm not an x86 assembler expert (too hard to read, bad design). See page 3-55 of the link posted by @Jester. That clearly states the `AND` instruction sets the flags (notsure what `ANDL` is, this is not given in the manual - I presume a syntax variation). Note this is normal behaviour for ALU instructions on most architectures. And the `TEST` instruction behaves identical, but witout changing destination.

Comment: Thanks missed that edit.  Feel free to edit yourself too.  I'm only concerned with leaving an accurate answer, as it has already been accepted.

Comment: It's ok for me now. Having a peek into the x86 instruction set reminded me why I did avoid programming this architecture in assembler again. Just look at the bunch of `AND`-Variants, with prefix, etc. What a crap of instruction set. Just compare with the 680x0 which was released about the same time.

Comment: @Olaf: Yep pretty much VHS vs Betamax all over again.

Comment: @EricJ.: You`re US? Never heard about Video 2000, I suppose? ;-)

Comment: Video 2000... the only domestic video system in which you could use both sides of the video tape, just like a regular audio cassette :D . It was never a real competitor: VHS was ubiquous at the time, and Betamax was adopted by professional equipment, so the competition was between these two. Video 2000 died some years earlier

Comment: To clarify this, note that testl %edx,%eax does not modify eax, it only sets the flags. andl %edx,%eax modifies eax and it also sets the flags. When GCC generated the assembly code was this a debug build or an optimized build? Also, at least in the case of Microsoft compilers, if just testing a register for zero or non-zero, usually orl %eax,%eax is used instead of testl.

Comment: Just looking at the generated code I think one can asume this was compiled in GCC with no optimizations. The compiler created the equivalent of a parse tree that emitted the code for the `(bitmask & bit)` and then emitted separately a `test` for the `if`. Generally GCC doesn't do instruction combining with no optimizations. At a level of -O1 I would expect them at a minimum to be instruction combined to eliminate one of the instructions. If anyone wants to see the original homework it is [here](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece391/assignments/ps/ps1_sp2015.pdf)